# script execution after logout

Tags: shell-script, debian, gnome

I used this logout and suspend script, bound to a keyboard shortcut under Debian Jessie with Gnome desktop:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ sleep 8; sudo systemctl suspend; } & 
gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

Now with Stretch this does not work any more. A quick test revealed that the command following sleep never get executed (I replaced the suspend part with a touch command). Does anyone have an idea why? What could have changed between Debian 8 and 9 or between Gnome 3.16 and 3.22?
Any recommended way to get around this?

Comment: It's possible that when logging out, any backgrounded jobs are being terminated.  Try rather than running your suspend process in a backgrounded code block, using `screen` or `nohup` to insulate your suspendifier from such cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here as I might have found the culprit.

My Debian 9 installation has systemd version 232. Looking though the [systemd changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS) this is what I found for version 230, dated May 2016:

> systemd-logind will now by default terminate user processes that are
>   part of the user session scope unit (session-XX.scope) when the user
>   logs out. This behavior is controlled by the KillUserProcesses=
>   setting in logind.conf, and the previous default of "no" is now
>   changed to "yes". This means that user sessions will be properly
>   cleaned up after, but additional steps are necessary to
>   allowintentionally long-running processes to survive logout (...)

The easiest fix seems to be to apply `nohup` as @DopeGhoti suggested in comment.